# No color in vi when called from python's script

Tags: python, vim, vi

When I edit a file with vi like :

```
vi .bashrc
```

I have colors.

When in python's script I have :

```
os.system("vi .bashrc")
```

I don't.

Why (I'm guessing that I open a different shell but I can't figure why the settings are different)? And how to solve this ?

I am running fedora and my shell is bash.

```
vi --version
```

gives :

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3
```

Comment: Are you running `vi` as the same user on the same machine in both cases?

Comment: Same machine, same user, same terminal (terminator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose it's because You have alias to vim, so calling `vi .bashrc` from bash mean `vim .bashrc`

`os.system` has no information about your aliases, so it calls `vi` editor withot color-highlighting